# How can I add subnodes to GeoExt2 layer tree (jsfiddle and pic inside)

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a map with couple of layers and I want to have each layer in separate folder below the root.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/WGSQb/
```

I'm creating regular store and I have no idea how to alter the code to match my need (pics below):

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        model: "GeoExt.data.LayerTreeModel",
        root: {
            expanded: true,
            children: [{
                plugins: ['gx_overlaylayercontainer'],
                expanded: true
            }]
        }
    });
```

Here it how it looks now :

[image]

Here it what I want to accomplish (without using photoshop :) ) :

[image]